# replace the 2nd match skipping 1st match in C#

Tags: c#, windows, forms

i have a string which has 2 similar words..i want to replace the 2 second word but not the 1st one..any help??

Comment: cant' help you without an example / more details

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expressions and a lookbehind.

```
var replaceHello = "ABC hello 123 hello 456 hello 789";
var fixedUp = Regex.Replace(replaceHello, "(?<=hello.*)hello", "goodbye");
```

This will replace all instances of the word "hello" with "goodbye", except for the first.

Answer (score 0):

The `Regex` version is concise, but if you're not of the sort to use a regular expression, you could consider something more code heavy.

The `StringBuilder` class provides a way to replace within a given substring. In this extension method on `string`, we'll specify a substring that starts at the conclusion of the first applicable match. Some basic validation against arguments are in place, but I can't say I've tested all combinations.

```
public static string SkipReplace(this string input, string oldValue, string newValue)
{
    if (input == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("input");

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(oldValue))
        throw new ArgumentException("oldValue");

    if (newValue == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("newValue");

    int index = input.IndexOf(oldValue);

    if (index > -1)
    {
        int startingPoint = index + oldValue.Length;
        int count = input.Length - startingPoint;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(input);
        builder.Replace(oldValue, newValue, startingPoint, count);

        return builder.ToString();
    }

    return input;
}
```

Using it:

```
string foobar = "foofoo".SkipReplace("foo", "bar");
```